# How to retrieve POST parameters containing a json object in PHP

Tags: php, json

I need to write codes in PHP to get some parameters POST to my page. One of these parameters is a json object.

I know in general. You can use following code to get POST values.

```
$value=$_POST["pram_name"];
```

And if only POST a json object to the page. I can do:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj=json_decode($json, true);
```

But if someone post several parameters with 1 json object. I cannot use above method to get the data.

Does anyone know a way to do so?

I know a way to work around this by putting the parameters in the json object. For some reason, the sender of the POST values cannot do that.

Thank you.

Comment: use of cURL would help out.. http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: JSON is just string, you should be able to get the value using `$_POST['json_string']`, if the request was sent correctly.